# LogicApp reading from Sharepoint subfolders

Tags: sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

Is it possible logicapp to read from the Sharepoint subfolder. Tried with the Get Files (Properties Only) still can't read files from the subfolders...

[image]

Comment: Do you get an error? If not what does it return? Anything? Can you show us the output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is something that you can follow to achieve your requirement.

- I have used the same `Get files (properties only)` action as you have mentioned.

  [image]
- In the next step Im trying to check if the iterated file is a folder and checking for a particular folder that I want the files to be retrieved.

  [image]
- If the Condition is true, I'm trying to list all the files that are present in the folder and then retrieving the file. You can replace `Get File metadata using path` with `Get file Content` if you are trying to retrieve the file contents.

***RESULTS:***

Below is the file Structure in my Sharepoint

```py
├───Documents
├───SampleText.txt
├───Folder1
    ├───aaa.txt
    ├───bbb.txt
    ├───SubFolder1
        ├───ccc.txt
        ├───ddd.txt
```

[image]